# AND instruction causes Segmentation fault in x86-64

Tags: g++, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am studying GCC inline assembly (for x86-64) in c++, and analyzing "Optimizing subroutines in assembly language An optimization guide for x86 platforms" by Agner Fog. For practice, I  put an Agner Fog's asmlib code (strlen64.asm) to AT&T inline assembly.  but, my program receives signal SIGSEGV. the following code ran on "https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler" (g++), and debugged in gdb.

this is my code (In comments, There are the ASM to c++ codes for my study):

```cpp
# include<iostream>

__attribute__((naked))
size_t strlen_sse(const char* const str) {
    // rdi : str
    // rax : aligned_str, diff
    // rcx : misalign
    // edx : mask, bsf_result
    
    // xmm0 : zero
    // xmm1 : c16, cmp_result
    
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "movq %%rdi, %%rax       \n"  // const char*   aligned_str = str;
        "movl %%edi, %%ecx       \n"  // intptr_t      misalign    = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(str);
        "pxor %%xmm0, %%xmm0     \n"  // const __m128i zero        = _mm_setzero_si128();
        
        "and  -0x10, %%rax       \n"  // aligned_str = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(
                                      //   reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(aligned_str) & -16
                                      // );
        "and 0xf, %%ecx          \n"  // misalign = misalign & 15;
        "movdqa (%%rax), %%xmm1  \n"  // __m128i c16        = _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(aligned_str) ),
        "pcmpeqb %%xmm0, %%xmm1  \n"  //         cmp_result = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(c16, zero);
        "pmovmskb %%xmm1, %%edx  \n"  // int     mask       = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp_result);
        "shr %%cl, %%edx         \n"  // mask >>= misalign;                   
        "shl %%cl, %%edx         \n"  // mask <<= misalign;
        "bsfl %%edx, %%edx       \n"  // int bsf_result = __builtin_ctz(mask);
        "jnz 2f                  \n"  // if(bsf_result!=32) goto STRLEN_SSE_EXIT;
        
        "1:                      \n"  // do {
        "addq 0x10, %%rax        \n"  //   aligned_str += 16;
        "movdqa (%%rax), %%xmm1  \n"  //   c16        = _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(aligned_str) );
        "pcmpeqb %%xmm0, %%xmm1  \n"  //   cmp_result = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(c16, zero);
        "pmovmskb %%xmm1, %%edx  \n"  //   mask       = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp_result);
        "bsfl %%edx, %%edx       \n"  //   bsf_result = __builtin_ctz(mask);
        "jz 1b                   \n"  // } while(bsf_result==32);
        
        "2:                      \n" // STRLEN_SSE_EXIT:
        "subq %%rdi, %%rax       \n" // size_t diff = aligned_str - str;
        "addq %%rdx, %%rax       \n" // diff += bsf_result;
        "ret                     \n" // return diff;
        : /* Output */
        : /* Input  */
        : "%rdi", "%edi", "%rax", "%rcx", "%edx", "%xmm0", "%xmm1"
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << strlen_sse("online compiler and debugger for c/c++");
}
```

this is what I see in gdb:

```
0x0000555555555190      45          );
(gdb) stepi
0x0000555555555192      45          );
(gdb) stepi
0x0000555555555196      45          );
(gdb) disass strlen_sse
Dump of assembler code for function strlen_sse(char const*):
   0x0000555555555189 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000055555555518d <+4>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
   0x0000555555555190 <+7>:     mov    %edi,%ecx
   0x0000555555555192 <+9>:     pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
=> 0x0000555555555196 <+13>:    and    0xfffffffffffffff0,%rax
   0x000055555555519e <+21>:    and    0xf,%ecx
   0x00005555555551a5 <+28>:    movdqa (%rax),%xmm1
   0x00005555555551a9 <+32>:    pcmpeqb %xmm0,%xmm1
   0x00005555555551ad <+36>:    pmovmskb %xmm1,%edx
   0x00005555555551b1 <+40>:    shr    %cl,%edx
   0x00005555555551b3 <+42>:    shl    %cl,%edx
   0x00005555555551b5 <+44>:    bsf    %edx,%edx
   0x00005555555551b8 <+47>:    jne    0x5555555551d3 <strlen_sse(char const*)+74>
   0x00005555555551ba <+49>:    add    0x10,%rax
   0x00005555555551c2 <+57>:    movdqa (%rax),%xmm1
   0x00005555555551c6 <+61>:    pcmpeqb %xmm0,%xmm1
   0x00005555555551ca <+65>:    pmovmskb %xmm1,%edx
   0x00005555555551ce <+69>:    bsf    %edx,%edx
   0x00005555555551d1 <+72>:    je     0x5555555551ba <strlen_sse(char const*)+49>
   0x00005555555551d3 <+74>:    sub    %rdi,%rax
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   0x00005555555551d6 <+77>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x00005555555551d9 <+80>:    retq   
   0x00005555555551da <+81>:    nop
   0x00005555555551db <+82>:    ud2    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555196 in strlen_sse (
    str=0x555555556010 "online compiler and debugger for c/c++") at main.cpp:45
45          );
(gdb) Quit
```

I think that the "pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0" worked fine, because "print $xmm0" command showed:

```
(gdb) print $xmm0
$1 = {
   v4_float = {0, 0, 0, 0},           v2_double = {0, 0}, 
   v16_int8 = {0 <repeats 16 times>}, v8_int16  = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   v4_int32 = {0, 0, 0, 0},           v2_int64  = {0, 0}, 
   uint128  = 0                                                            
}
```

But, the following "and    0xfffffffffffffff0,%rax" causes Segmentation fault, and the program is terminated. I didn't understand the result, so instead I thought a possible problem that the signal SIGSEGV came from "movdqa (%rax), %xmm1". but, "info registers" command showed:

```
rax            0x555555556010      93824992239632
rbx            0x555555555270      93824992236144
rcx            0x55556010          1431658512
rdx            0x7fffffffecd8      140737488350424
rsi            0x7fffffffecc8      140737488350408
rdi            0x555555556010      93824992239632
rbp            0x7fffffffebd0      0x7fffffffebd0
rsp            0x7fffffffebc8      0x7fffffffebc8
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x7ffff7fabec0      140737353793216
r10            0x7ffff7e2e1d5      140737352229333
r11            0x7ffff7f225a0      140737353229728
r12            0x5555555550a0      93824992235680
r13            0x7fffffffecc0      140737488350400
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x555555555196      0x555555555196 <strlen_sse(char const*)+13>
eflags         0x10246             [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
```

"rax" is aligned by 16. How do I solve this problem? on the other hand, when executed the c++ code, worked well. (I am not used to English, so I am sorry if there is an awkward expression in the question). Thanks.

Comment: Did you miss a `$` on `-0x10` (and all other immediates)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!!. I put $ to the all immediates, then the program do worked fine!. when compiled,  the compiler give no any error messages or warnings on $. so I've thought that an immediate need no $ prefix necessarily.

Comment: When you omit the `$`, it is still a valid instruction but the wrong one - namely it ANDs the contents of address `-0x10` with `rax`.  That address is obviously not mapped, hence segfault.